# python - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'checkpoint_callback'

Tags: python, error-handling, nlp, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm getting this error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-2892cdd4e738> in <module>()
      5   max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
      6   gpus=1, #GPU
----> 7   progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
      8 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/argparse.py in insert_env_defaults(self, *args, **kwargs)
    343 
    344         # all args were already moved to kwargs
--> 345         return fn(self, **kwargs)
    346 
    347     return cast(_T, insert_env_defaults)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'checkpoint_callback'
```

... when I run this chunk:

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
  logger=logger, 
  checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
  callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
  max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
  gpus=1, #GPU
  progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)
```

The 'checkpoint_callback' is defined like this:

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
  dirpath="checkpoints",
  filename="best-checkpoint",
  save_top_k=1,
  verbose=True,
  monitor="val_loss",
  mode="min"
)
```

I can't figure out what's causing the error - can anyone help me?

View full source code here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hT7PDVb0oGSpLejMGFBMWzRKTPwsSwwS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am looking into pytorch_lightning github, I do not see `checkpoint_callback` variable in **init** (https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/blob/master/src/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py)

Are you sure thats how it's called? What do you want to achieve by passing this `checkpoint_callback`?

//edit:
I think you just have to append `checkpoint_callback` to `callbacks` list

Comment: It's there: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint.html

```checkpoint_callback``` saves the best model (based on validation loss). 

I had no luck with the append proposal

Comment: What does it mean no luck? Have there be another error or the result was incorrect?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I do like this: ```trainer = pl.Trainer(
  logger=logger,
  checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
  callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
  callbacks.append(checkpoint_callback),
  max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
  gpus=1,
  progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)
``` and get an syntax error: ```SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument```

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood how to append; I succesfully appended like this: ```trainer = pl.Trainer(
  logger=logger,
  callbacks=[early_stopping_callback, checkpoint_callback],
  max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
  gpus=1,
  progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)```

Comment: And I undestand that it worked? :)

Answer (score 0):

for saving the best model you may use `enable_checkpointing` True or False.